# TS 2339 Property 'property 1' does not exist on type 'IReturnState'.ts for custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom hook like this:

```
interface IReturnState {
  activeItemsNumber: React.MutableRefObject<number>;
};

export const useMyState = (items): IReturnState => {
  // some code
  return {
    activeItemsNumber
  };
};
```

When I try to use it in the page component, I cannot return a custom variable name like this:

```
const { number1 } = useDndState(widgets);
```

There is an error on `number1`:

```
Property 'number1' does not exist on type 'IReturnState'.ts(2339)
```

I have to return the same variable name: `activeItemsNumber`, which means I cannot reuse the custom hook to return a different variable name. What I want to do is this:

```
const { number1 } = useDndState(widgets);
const { number2 } = useDndState(channels);
```

Any idea how to do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rename the variables like this:

```
const { activeItemsNumber: number1 } = useDndState(widgets);
const { activeItemsNumber: number2 } = useDndState(channels);
```

or you can return a tuple instead of an object from the custom hook

```
export const useMyState = (items): IReturnState => {
  // some code
  return [activeItemsNumber];
};
```

and then you can do

```
const [ number1 ] = useDndState(widgets);
const [ number2 ] = useDndState(channels);
```